# Change ANSI Padding

Tags: sql-server

I have a developer asking to change the default ANSI padding from ON to OFF. Of course my initial response was NO and why would you want to do that...

"I don't want trailing spaces on NVARCHAR, NCHAR columns.
According to the documentation (links below) the setting cannot be changed after a column is created.  Also, it says  the setting is always on by default for NVARCHAR / NCHAR columns and you have to explicitly set it.

The reason I'm using 'N' types is to make the application unicode compatible.

Can we set it globally so that when we create new tables I don't have to worry to set it explicitly?

Here is the problem and why:
The padding is ON and I get unwanted trailing spaces.
The extra spaces mess up the front end validation because HTML doesn't account for unicode lengths."

Part of the problem is the sourced data is downloaded by analyst from internet sites and currently we don't have good data quality validation protocols, which is beyond this post.

Has anyone else had to deal with this? If so, can you provide alternative options that don't involve rewriting proc and functions.

These are SQL Server 2017 instances and databases.

Any Suggestions or links to articles are appreciated.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): *"ANSI_PADDING should always be set to ON."* If the developer has a reason they "need" to have that setting put to `OFF` then they need a *<REDACTED>* good reason. I suggest, before anything, finding that out, and then sharing it in the question. Then we can tell you why their reason is wrong and you can go back and tell them "No" (if the documentation telling you **"Don't do it"** wasn't good enough).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A note in the [SQL Server documentation on ANSI_PADDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has:

> ANSI_PADDING should always be set to ON.

That leaves little room for discussion. More importantly, from the same link:

> The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect the nchar, nvarchar,
> ntext, text, image, varbinary(max), varchar(max), and nvarchar(max)
> data types. They always display the SET ANSI_PADDING ON behavior. This
> means trailing spaces and zeros are not trimmed.

What you could do, if changing the existing code base is not feasible, is to work with triggers on the columns of interest. Have the trigger(s) trim trailing spaces if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The developer is not happy with Microsoft for creating a variable length data type that doesn't trim trailing spaces or zeroes. I don't think a change request will help him either :)

Comment: Hi @NC3. I don't think the developer you speak of has the right idea of what a storage data type is supposed to do. It is not supposed to trim strings automatically. I don't know of any environments that do, apart from the ANSI_PADDING setting and I know it is strongly discouraged to use it. Admittedly, I know only the environment I work in.

Comment: I disagree.  The overhead of having to trim a varchar everytime you use it would seem to outweigh storing it correctly in the first place.  Every data base I've worked on stored varchar with padding off.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we set it globally so that when we create new tables I don't have
> to worry to set it explicitly?

It is a session setting, the user could change it at will.

You could prevent/rollback the creation&changes of tables when ansi_padding is off with a database trigger.

```
--a bit too strict for tables that do not contain char/binary columns
create or alter trigger ansi_padding_must_be_on   
on database   
for CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE
as
begin
    --when ansi_padding off, rollback the table creation/alteration
    if SESSIONPROPERTY ('ANSI_PADDING') = 0 -- (16 & @@options) <> 16
    begin
        raiserror(N'ANSI_PADDING must be ON;', 16, 1);
        rollback;
    end
end
```

> If so, can you provide alternative options that don't involve
> rewriting proc and functions.

You could schedule a job which updates&rtrims each %varchar% column until the proper quality controls are in place.